# Query the Latest Data Based On Condition in Multiple Columns and Concat Them

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, concatenation, clause

I have a database like this

[employees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idPXG.png)

I try to query the latest job and salary for every employees based on latest s_from_date and t_from_date and concat it to one column "Current Employees"

I try to filter it with max(s_from_date) and max(t_from_date) but it didn't work

```
SELECT CONCAT (first_name,' ',last_name,' ',salary,' ',title) As "Current Employees" 
FROM employees WHERE s_from_date = (SELECT MAX(s_from_date) FROM employees) AND t_from_date = (SELECT MAX(t_from_date) FROM employees);
```

Comment: Providing data instead of images of it helps to get much faster recommendations from the community.it is one of the reasons that you get Downvote

Answer (score 0):

if you use phpmyadmin, it can tell where the error position, please see image bellow.

[image]

I think you missed "(" after "concat".

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name,' ',salary,' ',title) As Current Employees
FROM employees WHERE s_from_date = (SELECT MAX(from_date) FROM employees) AND t_from_date = (SELECT MAX(from_date) FROM employees)
```

Comment: Sorry I think it's typo, but even there is '(' after concat,, the output still missing some employee data I think it's cause the clause MAX(s_from_date) and MAX(t_to_date) but i still don't know the solution

Comment: can you show your database table structure, I want to see field type.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name,' ',salary,' ',title) As "Current Employees" 
FROM employees e1
WHERE s_from_date = (SELECT MAX(s_from_date) FROM employees e2
                    WHERE e2.first_name = e1.first_name AND e2.last_name = e1.last_name) 
     AND t_from_date = (SELECT MAX(t_from_date) FROM employees e3
                    WHERE e3.first_name = e1.first_name AND e3.last_name = e1.last_name);
```

If your `employees` table has `id`/`employee_id` column, instead of using `last_name` and `first_name` in condition of 2 subqueries, you could change it to `e2.id = e1.id`, `e3.id = e1.id`.